# What is the meaning of "I could pretend you were his"?

Tags: meaning

In Thriller/Drama *Faster (2010)* film, Driver thinks that his father involved in his brother Gary death, 
so his mother corrects him:

> Mother: Because he loved your brother too much. I'm sorry. And that's
>   the truth and that's not your fault. **It wasn't like I could pretend
>   you were his**. He was reminded of that every time he looked at you. You
>   never stood a chance. Sorry that I couldn't That I didn't protect
>   you.
>
> Driver: Gary was the only one who ever cared for me.
>
> Mother: Why'd he pull you in on that job?

Sentence stopped at "**his**" word, So How to understand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen the movie either, but from context, she probably means that "Driver" is not really the son of the person called his father. His mother apparently had relations with another man.

In English we use the possessive to indicate family relationship. "Mr Jones is my father", "Sally is George's daughter", etc. We often leave out the relationship when it is implied by context. Like if you were picking up your child at pre-school, you might say, "Sally is mine". If she's 5 years old than obviously she's your daughter and not your mother or your wife. (Well, unlikely she's your wife in most societies, anyway.) In this case, she's talking about his supposed father and then saying "I couldn't pretend you were his", so presumably she means "his son".

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen the movie. But from the limited context you gave, I assume she is saying Driver is not the father's son. Maybe she had him with another man. The full sentence is "It wasn't like I could pretend you were his son." The word son is left out and just assumed.